# Am I a toroid or not?

Tags: general-topology

I heard that topologically (*whatever that is, me not good at math*), a donut and a mug are the same thing.
Both have *a hole going all the way through* them.

I found this animation transforming one into the other [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mug_and_Torus_morph.gif). It nicely illustrates the matter.

[image]

I wondered what other things are also donuts and mugs.
A ring, necklace, headband,...  I guess this list goes on and on.

**Am I on that list too?**

It seems to be a common thing among humans to have *a hole going all the way through*. On one side you put food in and it comes out at the other one in a slightly modified form. This is different from beverages that are apparently soaked up by the donuts-to-be and squeezed out later.

So far I feel quite toroidal, but some doubts remain:

Next to the hole where the food goes in, there are two more holes (for air, I guess) that are connected to the food hole (and therefore also to the other one). All in all there are 4 holes connected to each other, not just 2.

Does that still count as a toroid?

Comment: Toroids dream about manifolds homotopically equivalent to electric sheep.

Comment: Nah, we're probably a [genus 3  or 4 surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29). This of course excludes arteries and other more complicated structures (in which case our genus is much higher). I really have zero anatomical knowledge though, so someone else might be able to give a precise answer.

Comment: No. The surface of your body is a higher genus surface. I don't have the patience to actually count the genus, but given a sufficiently detailed anatomical diagram, you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: Technically, humans are made out of atoms, so once you reach a deep enough level of nitpicking, you discover that you can't put a continuous topology on them. At a lower level of nitpicking, you have thousands of millions of tiny holes like blood vessels and so on, so the answer is probably completely intractable that way too.

Comment: @Chappers: The solution, as with all amusing things, is to not think quite that hard :)

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh, my apologies. I thought we were looking for a correct answer, rather than a reasonable one! ;-)

Comment: Many of us increase our genus with body piercings.